# Implement my own maplist in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, maplist

I want to implement my own maplist in Prolog .

Given the following :

```
myMaplist(Goal, [Elem1|Tail1], [Elem2|Tail2]) :-
        apply(Goal, [Elem1, Elem2]), 
        myMaplist(Goal, Tail1, Tail2).
```

What is the `apply` operator , and how can I replace it with something that 
is **not** a library system call ?

Comment: call/1..8 are part of the ISO/IEC 13211-1 standard of Prolog. So these are not "library system calls".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your Prolog has call/N, use it:

```
myMaplist(Goal, [Elem1|Tail1], [Elem2|Tail2]) :-
        call(Goal, Elem1, Elem2), 
        myMaplist(Goal, Tail1, Tail2).
```

otherwise build the call with univ, and use call/1

```
myMaplist(Goal, [Elem1|Tail1], [Elem2|Tail2]) :-
        Pred =.. [Goal, Elem1, Elem2],
        call(Pred),
        myMaplist(Goal, Tail1, Tail2).
```

**edit** thanks to @false for pointing out that I must correct. To be true I posted that code without test, nevertheless I surely overlooked the bug... Here a correction

```
myMapList(_, [], []).
myMapList(Goal, [Elem1|Tail1], [Elem2|Tail2]) :-
    Goal =.. [P|A],
    append(A, [Elem1, Elem2], Ac),
    Pred =.. [P|Ac],
    call(Pred),
    myMapList(Goal, Tail1, Tail2).
```

test:

```
?- myMapList(myMapList(=),[[1,2,3],[a,b,c]],L).
L = [[1, 2, 3], [a, b, c]] .
```

Comment: It does ,but I'm not allowed to use it (HW).

Comment: I can't use any system / library calls . Any alternatives ? 10x !

Comment: then there are chances you can't use maplist either. Defining your own seems like cheating...

Comment: you should state what's allowed then, without builtins you cannot neither use bare arithmetic...

Comment: @ron: you always need some built-in call to do this. And call/1..8 is ISO. apply/2 is 1970s. It's not your fault :-)

Answer (score 1):

Pure prolog is based on first-order logic meaning that you cannot have predicates as arguments of other predicates. Therefore, you cannot implement a mapping predicate.

regarding `apply/2`: [swipl manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=apply/2)

Comment: On the other hand: call/1..8 can be implemented in first-order logic - the generality of 2nd order is not needed.